# Min/Max width of div container with css

Tags: html, css

I've basically created a rough template of a grid so to speak. There's the top row, which runs all the way across, the second row, which has two columns, the third row, which has two columns, and the bottom row, which runs all the way across.

Right now everything is fixed at a certain size. What I want to do is make it so that if the user resizes their window the div containers will shrink to a minimum size, and also if they expand their window set a maximum size. Any suggestions are appreciated. Below is my code. Excuse the inline CSS, I don't normally code that way.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test file</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="content-container" style="width:1500px; background:white;">

<div id="top-wrapper" style="width:100%; float:left; padding-bottom:50px; padding-top:50px; background:blue;">

<div id="top-strip" style="width:100%; text-align:center;"> 
<div id="toDesktopRecentTabs" style="float:left; width:20%;">Test</div>
<div id="toDesktopCustomize" style="float:left; width:20%;">Test</div>
<div id="toDesktopBuildingInventory" style="float:left; width:20%;">Test</div>
<div id="toDesktopDCStandards" style="float:left; width:20%;">Test</div>
<div id="toDesktopSupportingDocs" style="float:left; width:20%;">Test</div>
</div> 

</div>

<div id="row-container" style="float:left; width:100%; background:red;">

<div id="left" style="clear:left; float:left; width:45%; height:150px; padding:20px; margin:0 0 0 20px; display:inline; background:purple;">
<p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<div id="right" style="float:right; width:45%; height:150px; padding:20px; margin:0 20px 0 0; display:inline; background:green;">
<p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

</div>

<br style="clear:both;" />
<br />

<div id="row-container" style="float:left; width:100%; background:red;">

<div id="left" style="float:left; width:45%; height:150px; padding:20px; margin:0 0 0 20px; display:inline; background:cyan;">
<p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<div id="right" style="float:right; width:45%; height:150px; padding:20px; margin:0 20px 0 0; display:inline; background:pink;">
<p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

</div>

<div id="footer" style="clear:both; background:yellow; text-align:left; padding:20px;">
        Copyright © Site name, 20XX
</div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ok, you want to know how to set the max-width or min-width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to set everything to have `width` in `%`, and use the CSS properties `max-width` and `min-width` in `px`.

## Step 1

You already have most of your values set in `%`, except for your `padding` and `margin` for your content blocks. So the first thing I've done is updated those to be in `%` as well. Second, you have given those content blocks a fixed `height`, which will need to be removed to prevent text from overflowing when the block gets more narrow, so I've removed that (Also abstracted the CSS):

**http://jsfiddle.net/hYtH8/**

#### Old CSS:

```
.left {
    float:left;
    width:45%;
    display:inline;
    height:150px;
    padding:20px;
    margin:0 20px 0 0;
}

.right {
    float:right;
    width:45%;
    display:inline; 
    height:150px;
    padding:20px;
    margin:0 0 0 20px;
}
```

#### New CSS:

```
.left {
    float:left;
    width:45%;
    display:inline;
    padding:2%;
    margin-left:1%;
}

.right {
    float:right;
    width:45%;
    display:inline; 
    padding:2%;
    margin-right:1%;
}
```

---

## Step 2

Now that we have done that, we can change everything to a flexible model with fixed boundaries. We change the top container to have `width:100%` instead of `width:1500px`, and then give it a `max-width` and `min-width`.

**http://jsfiddle.net/hYtH8/3/**

#### Old CSS:

```
#content-container {
    width:1500px;
    background:white;
}
```

#### New CSS:

```
#content-container {
    width:100%;
    max-width:1500px;
    min-width:800px;
    background:white;
}
```

And success!

---

## Extra

Couple notes. I noticed that you have duplicated `id`s throughout. `#row-container` and `#left`, for example. CSS only allows a single instance of `id`s, so we should switch these to `class`es. Additionally, you can float both content blocks to the `left` since you don't have any content in the middle. This will let you save some lines of code, and get rid of `.left` and `.right` entirely:

**http://jsfiddle.net/hYtH8/5/**

#### Old CSS:

```
#row-container {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:red;
}

#left {
    float:left;
    width:45%;
    display:inline;
    padding:2%;
    margin-left:1%;
}

#right {
    float:right;
    width:45%;
    display:inline; 
    padding:2%;
    margin-right:1%;
}
```

#### New CSS:

```
.row-container {
    float:left;
    width:98%;
    background:red;
    padding:0 1%;
}

.row-container div {
    float:left;
    width:46%;
    display:inline;
    padding:2%;
}
```

Comment: That's perfect, thank you so much. For some reason before I almost accomplished this doing something similar, but the content would get pushed down when re-sizing the page.

Comment: I'm glad I could help! It was probably being pushed down because of the padding being fixed, which would cause content to be too wide at certain widths.

Comment: Makes sense! One final question/challenge. If I were to want to center these floated containers, would I want to add the 'margin:0 auto' to the row container, or the individual div elements themselves?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I'm understanding what you are asking. In the latest jsFiddle (5), the boxes are centered in that the red space on both sides is equal. Do you want to center the text inside the boxes?

Comment: Centering the content inside the boxes = yes. Also, I'm developing specifically for IE8, and I find when you shrink the page it doesnt obey the minimum width specified, which in turns pushes the divs under each other as it gets smaller

Comment: IE8 recognizes `min-width` as long as you aren't in Quirks-mode. You need to make sure you have a DOCTYPE declared at the top to ensure this happens. To the centering, just use `text-align:center`. See: http://jsfiddle.net/hYtH8/6/

Answer (score 1):

I've added two styles to the #content-container DIV, which are:

```
#content-div {
    max-width:800px; //this container wont be bigger than 800px
    min-width:500px; //and wont be smaller than 500px
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/p57kj/)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test file</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="content-container" style="max-width:800px; min-width:500px; background:white;">

    <div id="top-wrapper" style="width:100%; float:left; padding-bottom:50px; padding-top:50px; background:blue;">

    <div id="top-strip" style="width:100%; text-align:center;"> 
    <div id="toDesktopRecentTabs" style="float:left; width:20%;">Test</div>
    <div id="toDesktopCustomize" style="float:left; width:20%;">Test</div>
    <div id="toDesktopBuildingInventory" style="float:left; width:20%;">Test</div>
    <div id="toDesktopDCStandards" style="float:left; width:20%;">Test</div>
    <div id="toDesktopSupportingDocs" style="float:left; width:20%;">Test</div>
    </div> 

    </div>

    <div id="row-container" style="float:left; width:100%; background:red;">

    <div id="left" style="clear:left; float:left; width:45%; height:150px; padding:20px; margin:0 0 0 20px; display:inline; background:purple;">
    <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="right" style="float:right; width:45%; height:150px; padding:20px; margin:0 20px 0 0; display:inline; background:green;">
    <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>

    </div>

    <br style="clear:both;" />
    <br />

    <div id="row-container" style="float:left; width:100%; background:red;">

    <div id="left" style="float:left; width:45%; height:150px; padding:20px; margin:0 0 0 20px; display:inline; background:cyan;">
    <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="right" style="float:right; width:45%; height:150px; padding:20px; margin:0 20px 0 0; display:inline; background:pink;">
    <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>

    </div>

    <div id="footer" style="clear:both; background:yellow; text-align:left; padding:20px;">
            Copyright © Site name, 20XX
    </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Would be helpful to explain what you did.

Comment: Tried to explain, ask me again if it isn't clear yet

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS "min-width" and "max-width" properties. You can set it as a %, a px, or even other measurements like cm.